# Conditional counting for group variables

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Shop_type": [1,2,3,3,2,3,1,2,1],
               "Self_managed" :     [True,False,False,True,True,False,False,True,False],
               "Support_required" : [True,True,True,False,False,False,False,False,True]})
```

My goal is to get an overview of the number of number of Self_managed shops and Support_required shops somewhat looking like this:

```
  Shop_type  Self_count  Supprt_count
0          1           1             2
1          2           2             1
2          3           1             1
```

Currently I use the following code to achieve this, but it looks very long and unprofessional. Since I am still learning Python, I would like to improve and have more efficient code. Any ideas?

```
df1 = df[df["Self_managed"] == True]
df1 = df1.groupby(['Shop_type']).size().reset_index(name='Self_count')
df2 = df[df["Support_required"] == True]
df2 = df2.groupby(['Shop_type']).size().reset_index(name='Supprt_count')
df = df1.merge(df2, how = "outer", on="Shop_type")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
df.groupby('Shop_type',as_index=False).sum()
Out[298]: 
   Shop_type  Self_managed  Support_required
0          1           1.0               2.0
1          2           2.0               1.0
2          3           1.0               1.0
```